Will solutions of SDE with different initializations intersect at some point?
Inspired by the result for ODE here, which shows that solutions to the same ODE with different initializations do not intersect, I am wondering if similar results also hold for SDE?
Consider the SDE $$dX_t=f(X_t,t)dt+g(X_t,t)dB_t,$$ if both $f,g$ are Lipschitz with linear growth, then there must exists a unique strong solution for any independent initialization. If we consider the equation with $X_0=Z$ and $X_0=Y$, will there exist some $t$ such that $X_t^Y=X_t^Z$ a.s., (or some other way to define 'intersection of the solutions' more properly)?
As mentioned, there does not exist such $t$ in ODE. I tried to extend the ODE results here, but it seems one essential part is that for ODE, the uniqueness of solution is ensured on the interval $[-a,a]$, meaning that you can can extend the solution uniquely to the left-hand direction, so that the result follows. But for SDE, seems the unique results are only for the right-hand direction, and I am not sure whether a similar proof can be obtained. Any existing results can help?

Sorry, are you asking whether it's possible for such a $t$ to exist, or whether it's impossible for such a $t$ to exist?

Sorry I am not sure which the case it should be. I have modified the description to make it more clear. Thanks.

Proving that solutions with different initial conditions and driven by the same Brownian motion do not intersect is an important step in defining solution flows of an sde. I would imagine proof of this non-intersection property would be in Kunita's Stochastic Flows and Stochastic Differential Equations. If the two solutions a driven by a pair of Brownian motions, then one can couple the Brownian motions in such a way that the two solutions intersect in finite time (under some hypotheses on $f$ and $g$). See Lindvall and Rogers 1986.
